# When is applicationWillUpdate called?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I cannot work out when it it called in my project. The project is an iOS one inherited from someone else, and it uses irrlicht. I am having memory issues so have tried to print out the used/free memory in the applicationWillUpdate function.
It prints mostly when I expect it to, but on some screens it continues to print after the 'scene change' from one class to another has finished - and stops a few sseconds later.

Does anyone know exactly when this function would be called?

Comment: I have just had an 'xcode' tag removed because it's not appropriate, so this comment is to point out that I am in fact using xcode, and as far as I am aware applicationWillUpdate is a native function.

Comment: Please be aware that the xcode tag is for questions about the xcode IDE not code that you actually doing in it. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info I was also corrected on this in the not to distant past. So it seems like a good idea to in lighted users like I was.

Comment: Also please be aware you could get the ios tag removed as well. As even though you are using ios this actually specific towards the ios device. I have just left it in because you have said your project is in ios.

Comment: This OSX method gets called in your iOS app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[-applicationWillUpdate:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSApplicationDelegate/applicationWillUpdate%3a) is a native method defined in NSApplicationDelegate protocol and has nothing to do with iOS (it's from AppKit which is OS X analogy to UIKit). Command-click the name of the method in code and see where it takes you (cmd+click jumps to method definition).

Comment: I had tried this but it jump to definition doesn't go anywhere for this function.